# how to add checkbox and checkall to grid in shieldui ASP.NET MVC

Tags: datagridview, datagrid, shieldui

I want to add a checkbox and check all to grid in shieldui ASP.NET MVC

[image]

Comment: Please try to add more details that will help the volunteer to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You can add [checkboxes](https://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/checkbox/selection) to the Grid's toolbar and cells and use the [selection](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/select) APIs to change the selection based on the events coming from the checkboxes.